# What would be the process to convert a fan control meant for an AC ceiling fan to one meant for a DC ceiling fan?

Tags: ac, dc, fan

My understanding is that the fan speed controls in wall switches are - unless specifically paired with a DC ceiling fan - meant for AC ceiling fans; and they work by controlling capacitance (I'm a little hazy on that part, but some more detail is [over in this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/325339/268820) and [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95199/268820).)

In contrast, DC ceiling fans receive full power from the wall, and then utilize some of that power to control the DC motor, and do *something* after receiving RF signals telling it to adjust the speed and direction.

In particular, my Monte Carlo fan receives RF signals that adjust the dimmness of the light and speed/direction of the fan. The RF controller in the fan uses two wires to talk to the LEDs and 3 wires to talk to the fan.

I would like to explore the possibility of replacing the RF controller in the fan with a *thing* of my own design that converts 'signal' from the normal wall dimmers (varied capacitance in the case of the fan control, and whatever the dimmer mechanism is for the light) into the 'signal' understood by the fan and the fan's leds.

I presume this would involve measuring what is provided to the leds/fan over those 2/3 wires using a multi-meter (or possibility an oscilloscope?). But I am completely lost as to what thing might be able to turn the signal from the wall into whatever it is that the leds/fan expects.

I recognize that without being able to say for certain what the leds/fan expects this is somewhat difficult to answer, but I am hoping someone would be able to suggest the process by which I can attempt this myself, what additional information to gather, and what device(s) are the most likely needed to do this so I can read up on them.

Comment: You'd pretty much have to start over with something sensibly designed for this purpose.  A "conversion" makes no sense.  That said, it's unclear that this thing you are calling a "DC ceiling fan" even *exists* rather than being a misunderstanding of how a typical mains-AC powered fan with a remote control receiver installed from the factory or as an upgrade behaves...  If in fact it's an ordinary RF controlled fan what you may want to do is rig up some Arduino-ish project to command it.

Comment: The way to go now is buy an ACDC BLDC 3 phase ceiling fan, quiet, efficient cheap now.  Look up Orient Industrial Inc.  I got 2 5600 CFM 14" fans for $80 each from Princess Auto. (not ceiling type but similar simple electronics

Comment: @ChrisStratton The fan is a 3MAVR52BSD, and yes it's a mains-AC powered fan with a DC motor.  I could create my own thing that sends the RF signals, but I am trying very hard to provide a wall-controllable option (not a remote) for the fans to cater to desires such as "I can't find the remote because the 1 year old loves play with remotes". For the automation side of things, I planned to use e.g. a Leviton DW4SF.

Comment: Marketing claims aside, it's dubious that is actually a DC motor.  But anyway, that a control scheme is RF doesn't preclude the transmitter being mounted in a  fixed location.  Questions about modifying products are off topic here, this site is reserved only for design questions and those which can be supported by comparable *engineering detail*.